# Intepretation of a vector basis when the matrix A is not n by n

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self studying Strang's "Linear Algebra and it's applications" and I had originally thought, after watching the lectures and reading section 2.3, that I understood what the basis of a vector space was, but this question makes me think that perhaps I do not.

> Choose three independent columns of U. Then make two other choices. Do the same for the A. You have found the bases for which spaces?

$$
U =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
        0 & 6 & 7 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\quad
 A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\
        0 & 6 & 7 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 9 \\
        4 & 6 & 8 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

My confusion comes from if I choose three independent columns plus two more this creates a 5 by 4 matrix, which (from my current understanding) by definition cannot be a basis because a basis is maximally independent, therefore adding more columns than n means it is no longer independent.

Any clarification will be very helpful to me to understand what seems to be a an important concept.

Comment: For A note that the last row is twice the first row. By definition, only one is in the base. Also 0 vector of U is not in the base. And linear combinations of other rows are also not in the base by definition

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to do these things separately for each matrix.  In particular, for $U$, we can select
$$
\pmatrix{
 \color{red}2  & \color{red}3 & 4 & \color{red}1 \\ 
 \color{red}0  & \color{red}6 & 7 & \color{red}0 \\
 \color{red}0  & \color{red}0 & 0 & \color{red}9 \\
  \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & 0 & \color{red}0 \\
}
$$
and from $A$, we can select
$$
\pmatrix{
        \color{red}2 & \color{red}3 & 4 & \color{red}1 \\
        \color{red}0 & \color{red}6 & 7 & \color{red}0 \\
        \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & 0 & \color{red}9 \\
        \color{red}4 & \color{red}6 & 8 & \color{red}2 \\
}
$$
In so doing, we have constructed a basis for the column space of $U$, and a basis of the column space of $A$.  Each basis has $3$ vectors.  The important observation here is that since $U$ is a row-reduced version of $A$, we can conclude that *because* the first, second, and fourth columns of $U$ are independent, it must be that the first, second and fourth columns of $A$ are independent.  This gives us a way to build a basis of the column space of *any* matrix, as long as we row-reduce it first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my interpretation of the question was that I was asked to create a 5x4 matrix - "Choose three independent columns of U. Then make two other choices." Would you make the same interpretation or is the question asking for something different?

Comment: I realize now that I have no idea what he means by "then make two other choices."  Where did you find this in the book? It certainly isn't in section 2.3.

Comment: It is question 6 in section 2.3, pp 98 of the fourth edition.

Comment: Wait, I have the wrong textbook. I thought it was "introduction"

Comment: So, I have no idea what the "two other choices" is supposed to refer to in this context.  Maybe look at questions 1-5 for a hint as to what he means.

Comment: Perhaps it is a typo then? I wondered if this might be the case but I wanted to make sure in case I was missing an important point.

Comment: I'm as clueless as you are at this point.  I do highly suggest looking at the 5 earlier questions, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help and trying to 'debug' this with me. I found Q 1-5 relatively straightforward and my answers matched those in the back of the book (answers for the odd numbers only unfortunately).

Comment: Okay, but I'm looking whether he asks you anything *similar*, perhaps something involving making "$\_$ other choices"